# Why Site.css doesn't work with elements of partial view?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning ASP.NET mvc and I created a new project. From what I realized, the `@RenderBody()` starts by opening the `index.cshtml` and the `_Layout.cshtml` is loading the `Site.css` file.

The problem is that I can't edit the elements of this index.cshtml with css.

My index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <form>

            <div className="files">
                <h4>Select Files:</h4>

                <div className="radio-btn" >
                    <div className="radio">
                         <input type="radio" value="general" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="radio">
                        <input type="radio" value="avail" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in Site.cshtml I add this:

```
...
.radio-btn {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 0 10px 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: baseline;
}
```

but it doesn't work... if I change something of body it works, but something on index.cshtml doesn't change

Someone can help?

Comment: `className` should be `class`.  You use `className` only from JavaScript.  In HTML you use the `class` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `<div class="radio-btn" >`.. I'm not sure what `className` is used for

Comment: Thank you, I just copied the code of a project of mine in react and didn't remember that

Comment: Sorry, you know if it is possible to use ag-grid in mvc?

Comment: @CatarinaBatista ag-grid runs client-side, so it is completely unrelated to MVC. Yes, you can use it with MVC.

Comment: if you knowhow, can you check my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59739057/is-it-possible-to-use-ag-grid-in-asp-net-mvc)?